# How I can use a DataObject on MacOS (Drag and Drop files)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.mac

DataObject is part of System.Windows and not available in Xamarin.Mac. So how can I do a workaround. I want to create a drag n drop function with a external file. On Windows I can do this with a DataObject.

I already searched for alternatives, tried it with NSUrl but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Drag into your app:

All NSView-based classes have a `RegisterForDraggedTypes` method that you pass what you want to accept (in your case a `UTType.FileURL` as you are passing something into the app, assumably a file from Finder).

So in this case I have a `NSTableView` that accepts files, adds them the the table and fires an notification that causes an `NSTask` to process them (it is a FFMPEG-based task).

```
tableView.RegisterForDraggedTypes(new string[] { UTType.FileURL };
```

From there it depends upon the type of NSView you are dragging into, but for example with an `NSTableView`, you assign its data delegate a `NSTableViewDataSource` subclass which you have overridden `ValidateDrop` and `AcceptDrop`.

In `NSTableViewDataSource.ValidateDrop` you confirm if the drop contains file(s) that you will accept. In this case, as long as it is a file of any type I accept:

```
public override NSDragOperation ValidateDrop(NSTableView tableView, NSDraggingInfo info, nint row, NSTableViewDropOperation dropOperation)
{
    var operation = NSDragOperation.Copy;
    using (var pasteBoard = info.DraggingPasteboard)
    {
        foreach (var item in pasteBoard.PasteboardItems)
        {
            if (!item.Types.Contains(UTType.FileURL))
            {
                operation = NSDragOperation.None;
            }
            item.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return operation;
}
```

In in `NSTableViewDataSource.AcceptDrop`, you actually process the files from the drop.

```
public override bool AcceptDrop(NSTableView tableView, NSDraggingInfo info, nint row, NSTableViewDropOperation dropOperation)
{
    using (var pasteBoard = info.DraggingPasteboard)
    {
        if (pasteBoard.PasteboardItems.Length > 0)
        {
            var range = new NSRange(-1, 0);
            foreach (var item in pasteBoard.PasteboardItems)
            {
                if (item.Types.Contains(UTType.FileURL))
                {
                    var finderNode = item.GetStringForType(UTType.FileURL);
                    // you have a file from macOS' finder, do something with it, assumable in a table view you would add a record/row....

                    var url = NSUrl.FromString(finderNode);
                    // url has the file extension, filename, full path, etc...

                   Post a notification / Add a task to GCD / etc...
                }
                item.Dispose();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### Drag out of your app:

Lets assume you have an `NSView` subclass that you wish to drag a "file" out of and into Finder or any app that accepts file drops. Implement the interfaces; `INSDraggingSource` and `INSPasteboardItemDataProvider` on your `NSView` subclass.

In the `MouseDown` event, start your drag for `UTType.FileURL` types:

```
public override void MouseDown(NSEvent theEvent)
{
    var pasteboardItem = new NSPasteboardItem();
    pasteboardItem.SetDataProviderForTypes(this, new string[1] { UTType.FileURL });

    var draggingItem = new NSDraggingItem(pasteboardItem);
    var fileDragIcon = new NSImage("theDraggingIcon.png");
    draggingItem.SetDraggingFrame(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0,0,40,40), fileDragIcon);
    BeginDraggingSession(new NSDraggingItem[1] { draggingItem }, theEvent, this);
}
```

In the `ProvideDataForType` place the file url onto the pasteboard:

```
public void ProvideDataForType(NSPasteboard pasteboard, NSPasteboardItem item, string type)
{
    if (type == UTType.FileURL )
    {
        var url = new NSUrl("/Users/Sushi/Desktop/StackOverflow.png", false);
        url.WriteToPasteboard(pasteboard);
    }
}
```

Note: That is just one way to transfer a file, there are three other file drag transfers, you can also provide an array of urls, a promise to create the file yourself later and actually inserting the file's data into the pasteboard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but `UTType` is part of Xamarin.iOS. It belongs to the `MobileCoreServices` - does a similar method exist?

Comment: @MarcoSadowski Yes it does, that is a part of the Xamarin.iOS|Mac unified APIs  and is available via the "`Xamarin.Mac` Modern" framework.

Comment: ah sorry my fault. So as far as I tested it I can only use `UTType.FileURL` for incoming files, not outgoing files. I know how I can do this with a String `var text = new NSDraggingItem((NSString)"Hello World");` but with a file... I got a Idea. I check out if I could load a file to the Pasteboad. Which me luck :D

Comment: @MarcoSadowski You want to drag out of your app, into your app, or between views of your app? Your original question sounds like into your app?

Comment: the goal is to create a Drag n Drop Session out of the App (into finder, other programs, etc.). Here is the special part: The file is not part of the application. The application only have the path of the file.

Comment: @MarcoSadowski easy to do, see my updated answer (**`Drag out of your app:`**)

Comment: Hey @SushiHangover! you said there are three other file drag transfers. Is there an article, documentation or something similar available online. I would like to read more about it but can't find anything :)

Comment: @MarcoSadowski Its all in the apple docs, search those docs for Introduction to Drag and Drop (i think that is a title)